# How are push notifications displayed on iOS 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I was wondering how push notifications were displayed on screen for iOS 4? Since there is no notification center (iOS 5) will the push notification instead automatically be displayed as an alert or must I implement this myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code/logic to implement to send "message" push notifications is no different in iOS 4 vs iOS 5. the only difference is the appearance to the user which is a UIAlertView style notification with a "Go to App" button and an ok button. Also be aware there is no notification center that will keep track of old notifications.